# C++-equivalent to incompletely initialized arrays in C?

Tags: c++, c

When I transform code from C to C++ I sometimes encounter language constructs that are C, but compatible with C++. Usually I want to transform the code in the **least intrusive** way. But I have one case where I find that very difficult:

In C you can **declare** an array and **initializing**... well... **parts** of it using *"designators"*, the rest is zeroed out *(Edit: I wrote "left to randomness" here, first)*:

```
int data[7] = {
    [2] = 7,
    [4] = 9,
};
```

This is not valid C++-code, though (luckily). So I will have to use a different strategy.

While I can see a non-intrusive way in C++11:

```
static const map<int,int> data = { {2,7}, {4,9} };
```

what should I do when C++11-features are not available yet?

- Can I circumvent a **runtime initialization**?
- Is there a way to initialize similar kind of mapping in a **"literal"** way?
- What is **least intrusive** to the code that uses `data`?

Comment: So you only intend to use the indices `2` and `4`, or do you still have a need for the other indices?

Comment: Usually those are "static const" mappings, mapping enumeration values to human readable strings. They are not changed in any way at runtime.

Comment: Did you mean `pedant`? or `dependant`?

Comment: @PeterWood: I changed the title to "C++-equivalent". "pendant" was not a good word.

Comment: "*Can I circumvent a runtime initialization?*" What makes you think that the C++11 solution *isn't* runtime initialization?

Comment: @NicolBolas My C++-11 example was mainly to point out the `const static` semantics, the wish to have it compile-time (like the C original) was not connected to the C++11-code. But nontheless -- not a guarantee, of course. And you are right: Since neither the `map`-c'tor nor the the `pair`-c'tor are `constexpr` (right?) it probably isn't. The beguiling "concise" notation would suggest it though -- but in general I agree, it is probably not compile-time.

Comment: +1 for the question. Comment: Apart from the likely impossibility of initializing a `std::map` at compile time (C++11 or not), is replacing an array with a structure as complex as a `std::map` really an option? It would have an impact on the speed of every single look-up, and every single modification of the data. ... oh I just saw your earlier comment about this being used to map values to human-readable strings. So speed doesn't matter, I suppose.

Comment: @jogojapan Yes, my first encounter with this was a read-only mapping from int-to-strings. All my encounters were read-only mapping-like, not all were to strings. I think a `map` is adding a reasonable overhead into the program when dealing with read-only data. We could discuss the overhead in writing scenarios, too, but let's not do that here ;-)

Comment: For the record, the unspecified indices in the initializer list are zeroed, not "left to randomness".  This works similarly to constructs like int a[10] = {0}; - it's shorthand for zeroing anything not specified.

Comment: @chazomaticus: Oh, right. Thank you! I found it in *n1124* §6.7.8.(21) with an explicit example in (34). It is called "designator" -- I did not know that. I will amend the question to not confuse later readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If uniform initialization is not available, the `std::map<int, int>` could be initialized using [`boost::assign::map_list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of):

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
static const std::map<int,int> data = boost::assign::map_list_of(2,7)(4,9);
```

Comment: Good solution. I wasn't aware of that feature of *boost*. But introducing boost into a project is quite a mouthful that one can only consider to be "non-intrusive" by *some* definitions of "intrusive". I will use this when *boost* is already in the project, I wonder if there is a boost-less way, too?

Comment: There is no way without 3rd party libs. Except the way to write your own  :)

Answer (score 11):

Well unless the size of the array is totally insane, you can always do this

```
int data[7] = {
    0,
    0,
    7, // #2
    0, 
    9  // #4
    // the rest will be 0-initialized
};
```

Works in compile time too

Comment: Good idea, yes. In fact, I think I encountered that insane size. But anyway, I could generate that source-code. Hrmm.... yes I like that.

Comment: This is without question the method that's "least intrusive to the code that uses `data`".

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `map<int, int>` you can backport `std:array` (or a minimal equivalent) from C++11, and use a Boost.Assign-style builder facility:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t N> struct array { T data[N]; };
template<typename T, size_t N> struct build_array: public array<T, N> {
   build_array &operator()(size_t i, const T &t) {
      this->data[i] = t;
      return *this;
   }
};

array<int, 7> data_array = build_array<int, 7>()(2, 7)(4, 9);
int (&data)[7] = data_array.data;
```

Comment: I kind of like that, yes. My only concern is that it is obviously runtime initialization, too. I would surmise that the body of `()` is too complex for a compiler to unroll at compile-time (it would not be `constexpr` in C++11). But your example brings me to the possibility that I could initialize `data`  with a `int* initData()` function -- ignoring "memory leaks".

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you do:

```
int data[7];
data[2] = 7;
data[4] = 9;
```

looks very-very similar =)

Comment: That is runtime and that's one of my current options, yes. Alas, the code may be in a library I port. And the initialization must then be done in a function that is guaranteed to be called, i.e. at library initialization. Some libs do not have such a function so that you cant be sure that every client code is initializing the map properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `boost::assign`
You can create it's simple analogue:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
std::map<T1, T2> cre(std::map<T1, T2> & m)
{
   return std::map<T1, T2>();
}

template<class T1, class T2>
std::map<T1, T2> & ass(std::map<T1, T2> & m, T1 const & p1, T2 const & p2)
{
   m[p1] = p2;
   return m;
}

std::map<int, int> data = ass(ass(cre(data), 2, 3), 7, 6);
```

Comment: You and @ecatmur chose the same solution. Ok.